# Create a circle next to a TextField using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am working with a Box element which contains Textfield elements. I was wondering If i can create a circle for each TextField. I have tried using css like below.

```
     circle: {
        display: 'flex',
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        color: 'green',
        borderRadius:'50%',
      },
```

```
<TextField 
          className={classes.circle}
          id='consumptionInkWhPerkmAltitudeGain -number'
          label='Altitude Gain(TomTom)'
          type='number'
          value={customConsumptionDetails.consumptionInkWhPerkmAltitudeGain }
          color = "secondary"
          onChange={handleConsumptionDetailsParameterChange('consumptionInkWhPerkmAltitudeGain')}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}

        />
```

but without luck.
For a better understanding of what I want to do I will leave a picture bellow.
[image]

How can I create something similar with what is in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the styling with `className`, you can easily modify the code below, hope it helps!

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea />
      <span className="circle"></span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the `styles.css`:

```
.circle {
  display: flex;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bardeen-dd4h1w?file=/src/App.js